# Parameterize callback function

Tags: c++, function

I've created a dictionary which has a traverse function which takes a callback for each node that is traversed.

Signature:

```
void traverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
```

Implementation:

```
template < class KeyType, class ItemType>
void HashedDictionary< KeyType, ItemType>::traverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const {
    HashedEntry<KeyType, ItemType> *currPtr;
    for (int i = 0; i < hashTableSize; i++) {
        currPtr = hashTable[i];
        while (currPtr != nullptr) {
            ItemType currItem = currPtr->getItem();
            visit(currItem);
            currPtr = currPtr->getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

currently I'm using this callback

```
void visit(Person& p) {
    cout << p.getName() << ": " << p.getMonth() << "/" << p.getDay() << "/" << p.getYear() << endl;
}

d->traverse(visit);
```

However, I'd like to add a parameter for month, where the name is only printed if the month is a certain value.

How can I pass the month to this function? Something to the effect of:

```
d->traverse(visit(4));
```

For the 4th month...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your `traverse()` method to accept any callable type for the visitor, eg:

```
template < class KeyType, class ItemType, class VisitorType >
void HashedDictionary< KeyType, ItemType>::traverse(VisitorType visit) const {
    HashedEntry<KeyType, ItemType> *currPtr;
    for (int i = 0; i < hashTableSize; i++) {
        currPtr = hashTable[i];
        while (currPtr) {
            ItemType currItem = currPtr->getItem();
            visit(currItem);
            currPtr = currPtr->getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can pass in a functor or a function, eg:

```
struct visit {
    int month;
    visit (int mon) : month(mon) {}
    void operator()(Person& p) {
        if (p.getMonth() == month) {
            cout << p.getName() << ": " << p.getMonth() << "/" << p.getDay() << "/" << p.getYear() << endl;
        }
    }
};

d->traverse(visit(4));
```

```
void visitIfApril(Person& p) {
    if (p.getMonth() == 4) {
        cout << p.getName() << ": " << p.getMonth() << "/" << p.getDay() << "/" << p.getYear() << endl;
    }
}

d->traverse(visitIfApril);
```

```
template<const int month>
void visitIf(Person& p) {
    if (p.getMonth() == month) {
        cout << p.getName() << ": " << p.getMonth() << "/" << p.getDay() << "/" << p.getYear() << endl;
    }
}

d->traverse(visitIf<4>);
```

In C++11 and later, you can also pass in a lambda instead:

```
d->traverse(
    [](Person& p) {
        if (p.getMonth() == 4) {
            cout << p.getName() << ": " << p.getMonth() << "/" << p.getDay() << "/" << p.getYear() << endl;
        }
    }
);
```

The alternative is to give `traverse()` an additional user-defined parameter to then pass to the callback function, eg:

```
template < class KeyType, class ItemType, class UserType >
void HashedDictionary< KeyType, ItemType>::traverse(void visit(ItemType&), UserType user) const {
    HashedEntry<KeyType, ItemType> *currPtr;
    for (int i = 0; i < hashTableSize; i++) {
        currPtr = hashTable[i];
        while (currPtr) {
            ItemType currItem = currPtr->getItem();
            visit(currItem, user);
            currPtr = currPtr->getNext();
        }
    }
}

void visit(Person& p, int month) {
    if p.getMonth() == month) {
        cout << p.getName() << ": " << p.getMonth() << "/" << p.getDay() << "/" << p.getYear() << endl;
    }
}

d->traverse(visit, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I pass the month to this function?

In its current form, you can't. Your prototype for traverse is:

```
void traverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
```

If however it looked more like:

```
template<typename TraverseFunc>
void traverse(TraverseFunc& visit) const;
```

Then you could replace your function with a function object, i.e.

```
struct MyVisitor {
   int month;
   MyVisitor(int month) : month(month) {}
   // overload () operator
   void operator () (ItemType& item) {
     // do thing to item
   }
};
```

And then you would be able to do:

```
d->traverse(MyVisitor(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function pointer as well as all the parameters required by the function being passed as parameter. So in your case, you should pass `month` as a parameter to the `traverse` function.

**Signature:**

```
void traverse(void visit(ItemType&), int month) const;
```

`visit()` function should have a parameter month:

```
void visit(Person& p, int month);
```

Now you can call your traverse function like this:

```
d->traverse(visit, 4);
```

Comment: The dictionary presumably does not know anything about the item type.

Comment: @sp2danny why? It knows how it implements its items internally, and what type they hold. It doesn't need to know the specifics of the type in order to pass it to the callback

Comment: Dictionaries are typically templates, that accept any item type. It does not make sense that its visit function have an extra 'int month' parameter, and extra logic that will only work for some types

Comment: I agree with @sp2danny that a dictionary's visit function should be generic and should not have an extra 'int month' parameter. But I believe, `visit()` in this case is not a member function of the `HashedDictionary` class. It's a regular function which is being used as a callback function with a very specific use case.